# Configure IRazorViewEngine to search other assemblies for views in net6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0

I have views in multiple projects that i would like `IRazorViewEngine` to search. Currently it is only looking in the current assembly. For example, the following code is always unsuccessful when the view is in another project (that i have added as a project reference).

```
var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);
```

This works okay when the view is in the current assembly. I have inspected the result and the folder structure in the search location looks okay.

I have seen answers for this in net3 using fileproviders, however this doesn't seem to be available in net6.

Is there a way to specify which assemblies `IRazorViewEngine` should search?

**EDIT 1**
Here is the csproj contents:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you display the contents of your csproj file? I want to see the version you are using.

Comment: @Chaodeng Good point, I've added it to the question.

Comment: Do you have any errors in using fileproviders in the .net6 version?

Comment: @tayab why do you have "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" with "2.2.5" version?

Comment: @Chaodeng fileproviders are no longer available in .net6 as far as i know. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengineoptions?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @GuruStron 2.2.5 is the latest version of that package, regardless we don't use that package anymore so its been removed.